# actions-on-google: Account Linking failed using google oAuth server

Tags: actions-on-google

I am facing the Account linking issue.I have used Google outh after configuring the google platform for my project. I am attaching the logs from stackdriver below..Any clue on this?

> { "textPayload": "SYNC: Request ID 6388194814495650858 failed with
>   code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE", "insertId": "1ubv1mjg2ix7sp2", "resource": {
>   "type": "assistant_action", "labels": { "project_id":
>   "nov-lambda-try", "version_id": "", "action_id": "SMART_HOME_SYNC" }
>   }, "timestamp": "2019-01-17T12:22:45.026986120Z", "severity": "ERROR",
>   "logName":
>   "projects/nov-lambda-try/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions",
>   "receiveTimestamp": "2019-01-17T12:22:45.062133582Z" },

Comment: If you're getting an auth failure, you will need to check your authentication and SYNC responses to make sure everything is working as expected.

Comment: hi Nick, this is authentication failure when i have used the oAuth using google oAuth server. is there any specific settings needed for smart home when we configure the oAuth server in google cloud platform? this error happens before my cloud receives the SYNC request...

Comment: It should be a general OAuth integration. Nothing specific as far as I can tell. But you may want to try the OAuth playground to be sure: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: if you look at the error it says OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE, also i am getting an error Äccount Linking failed in the Google Home when i do account linking...Is there any time limit or approval needed for using the oAuth2 client id which i have got from google developers platform?

Comment: There's no delay or approval needed for auth to work successfully, so it could be an issue in your implementation.

Comment: For the smarthome fulfillment i am using Amazon API gateway, I dont see the request coming to the API gateway. If i use Amazon oAuth, i see the SYNC response is send properly and device is working with Google assistant properly. If i use google oAuth my smarthome fulfillment not receiving the SYNC request. I face this error. Any clue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're using Google oauth? You might be using an unsupported setup.

Comment: 1. In actions-on-Console, for my smarthome project, Account linking section i have given the oAuth2 client id and client secret which i have generated from the google cloud platform for the same project. Linking type :OAuth,Authorisation Code. Authorisation url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth Token url:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token and scope -Is this correct? profile. 2. Can you explain what is unsupported setup.?

Comment: You may not able to use Google's auth endpoints for authorization. You should switch to a different OAuth provider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is clear we can not use Google oAuth for authorisation.